# Regex to match Telephone Pattern logic

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex string to match telephone numbers using the following logic:

1) For NPA (area code), 3 digits,  the first digit is [2-9], 2nd and 3rd digit [0-9]

2) For NXX (exchange – next 3 digits after NPA) same rules as NPA.  In addition, the 3rd digit cannot be ‘1’ if the 2nd digit is ‘1’ (reserved for public service)

3) For XXXX (number – next 4 digits after NXX), [0-9] for each of the 4 digits.

I've completed steps 1 and 3 and part of 2 with the following string:

```
^\(?([2-9]{1})\)?([0-9]{2})?[-.*]?([2-9]{1})\)?([0-9]{2})?[-.*]?([0-9]{4})$
```

But I am stuck on trying to incorporate the logic stated here:

For NXX (exchange – next 3 digits after NPA) same rules as NPA.  In addition, the 3rd digit cannot be ‘1’ if the 2nd digit is ‘1’ (reserved for public service)

If anyone can help shine some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

False is what I want my regex not to match, while true is what I would want it continuing to match. It currently matches both sets .

False: `4807119320 4805119439 4809114739`

True: `4805218482 4805123848 4809128327 4809418482`

Comment: I think it would help if you can add some examples to your question that should and should not match.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct so here are two examples. False is what I want my regex not to match, while true is what I would want it continuing to match. It currently matches both sets .

False:
4807119320
4805119439
4809114739

True:
4805218482
4805123848
4809128327
4809418482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the second part the second digit can not be 1 if the third digit is 1, you could use a negative lookahead `(?!11)`to assert what is on the right is not 11.

Adding that to your pattern, it would look like:

```
^\(?([2-9])\)?([0-9]{2})?[-.*]?([2-9])\)?((?!11)[0-9]{2})?[-.*]?([0-9]{4})$
                                          ^^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9QLWjt/1)

**Note** that a lot of parts are optional due to the question mark like `\(?` and `\)?` and for the second closing parenthesis there is an opening parenthesis missing so this would also match `(2)33-2)21-2222`

If the opening and closing parenthesis should for the second part be the same as the first it could look like:

```
^\(?([2-9])\)?([0-9]{2})?[-.*]?\(?([2-9])\)?((?!11)[0-9]{2})?[-.*]?([0-9]{4})$
                               ^^^
```

If what is match in the first character class should be the same as in the second character class, you might also use another capturing group `([-.*]?)` and  a backreference `\3` so `(2)33-(2)212222` would not match:

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9QLWjt/2)

Comment: Thanks , this is what i was missing. I know i needed to do a look ahead and was just stuck on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using

> ^(?([2-9]))?([0-9]{2})?[-.*]?([2-9]))?((?!11)[0-9]{2})?[-.*]?([0-9]{4})$

Resolved my issue